# Python Opencv live desktop screen process

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to process live screen. There is a game about catching fish. You have to click on fish when it is in circle. I think that I can process my screen with opencv, find fish and click on it with pyautogui.

I did it but problem is program not fast enough to click. By the way game is a mini game in Metin 2 mmorpg. It is like a hack or bot but I just wondering if can I do that.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui
import time

while True:

    img=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(341,208,430,290))
    img_np=np.array(img)
    #gray=cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #lower=np.array([57,91,120])
    #upper=np.array([65,95,160])

    #mask=cv2.inRange(gray,95,130)

    #sonuc=cv2.bitwise_and(gray,gray,mask=mask)
    #cv2.imshow('frame',mask)


    degsk=np.argwhere(img_np==[123,90,57])
    if len(degsk)!=0:
        #print(degsk)
        yerx=341+degsk[int(len(degsk)/2),1]
        yery=208+degsk[int(len(degsk)/2),0]
        #pyautogui.click(x=yerx, y=yery)
        time.sleep(0.8)

    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF==ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

As you can see, first I tried mask the screen than I realise that it is not necessary so I found BGR value of fish and programed to find it in numpy array than I took value middle in the array and than i used mouse move function. As I said this is not fast enough to catch fish.

So the program is working but delayed for catch fish. How can I make faster this program?

[Game Screen Here](https://pasteboard.co/IIKwzUu.jpg)

Comment: Why using time.sleep(0.8) ?

Comment: You cannot hit consecutive so it need delay in there. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using mss is really fast. Try this:

```
import time

import cv2
import mss
import numpy


    with mss.mss() as sct:
        # Part of the screen to capture
        monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 800, "height": 640}
    
        while "Screen capturing":
            last_time = time.time()
    
            # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
            img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))
    
            # Display the picture
            cv2.imshow("OpenCV/Numpy normal", img)
    
            # Display the picture in grayscale
            # cv2.imshow('OpenCV/Numpy grayscale',
            #            cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY))
    
            print("fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))
    
            # Press "q" to quit
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

More information on https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I find `IPython` best for timing things, so if you start `IPython` and paste in the following code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

img=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(341,208,430,290))
```

You can then time a statement with:

```
%timeit img=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(341,208,430,290))
```

and I get this:

```
552 ms ± 5.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So, grabbing the screen takes over 500ms, so you are only going to get under 2 frames/second - without even processing it.

If you want to grab the screen faster, I would suggest `ffmpeg`. I installed it on my iMac running `macOS` with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

I can then see the list of available video sources and find what I need to record the screen with:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
```

**Sample Output**

```
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa7dcf05b40] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa7dcf05b40] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa7dcf05b40] [1] Capture screen 0             <--- THIS ONE IS THE SCREEN
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa7dcf05b40] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa7dcf05b40] [0] MacBook Pro Microphone
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fa7dcf05b40] [1] CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 Audio
```

So I know I need input 1 for the screen.

So, if I want to record the screen from top-left corner (0,0) at a width of 400px and height of 200px at 20fps for 10s and pass RGBA8888 data to my fishing program, I can do this:

```
ffmpeg -y -pix_fmt bgr0 -f avfoundation -r 20 -t 10 -i 1 -filter:v "crop=400:200:0:0" -f rawvideo - | ./fish.py
```

I can now use the following as my fishing program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time
import os, sys

# width, height
w, h = 400, 200

# Bytes per frame - assumes bgr0, i.e. 8-bits of blue, 8-bits red. 8-bits green and 8-bits junk
bytesPerFrame = w * h * 4

while True:
    img = sys.stdin.buffer.read(bytesPerFrame)
    if len(img) != bytesPerFrame:
        break
    # Process your video here
```

**Keywords**: pyautogui, screen grab, screen-grab, screengrab, slow, Mac, macOS, Python, capture, screen capture, ffmpeg, PIL, OpenCV

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try and I'll give feedback to you shortly.