# How can I make openCV record frames faster

Tags: python, performance, opencv

I'm trying to record my screen so that openCV can analyze it. But when I input more the code the program becomes very slow. I only have one `if` statement but I plan on putting in many more. Is there a way I can make this faster or optimize it?

Here is my code

```py
while True:
    screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1366, 768))
    screen_ = np.array(screen)

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(screen_, temp1, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    if thres <= max_val:
        temp_w = temp1.shape[1]
        temp_h = temp1.shape[0]

        top_left = max_loc
        bottom_right = (top_left[0] + temp_w, top_left[1] + temp_h)

        cv2.rectangle(screen_, top_left, bottom_right, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_4)

    else:
        pass

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(screen_, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    cv2.imshow("screen", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
```

Comment: grab, save to the file, analyse offline...

Comment: This is more or less for a online MMO I cant use it offline unfortunately

Comment: cheating in online games is usually frowned upon, even if you do that with python =) the problem you're describing has nothing to do with opencv grabbing -- i'm sure you get 30fps at least, the problem is you processing -- try to optimize that, or move it to a different CPU core, use multiprocessing etc.

Comment: My goal inst really to cheat its to make a kind of like OverWolf overlay. But I guess Python maybe to slow or I don't have enough experience with Python to figure it out. Sorry!

Comment: Or my computer might not be powerful enough

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089102/2836621

Comment: I will try once i wake up tommorow. Thanks nonetheless

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what your doing. I can't use ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i "" because I'm on Windows.

Comment: I was suggesting you apply the concept of recording your screen with `ffmpeg` rather than that you use the exact macOS commands... your question doesn't mention you're on Windows either, btw.

Comment: Yeah I tried looking up how to do it and I've had no luck.

Comment: These are my dshow outputs

`[dshow @ 06dacd00] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 06dacd00]  "HP Webcam"
[dshow @ 06dacd00]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_04ca&pid_707d&mi_00#8&1374df96&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 06dacd00] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 06dacd00]  "Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)"
[dshow @ 06dacd00]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{4F75981B-AE1E-4B79-A666-6E1CD5EEE767}"`

Comment: Sorry it's hard to read but I cant find any of the outputs that work

Comment: Don't put code or anything that requires formatting in the comments area. Instead, click `edit` under your question and update it in there where it is easily formatted and read without scrambling around through the comments. Thank you.

Comment: Dis you measure how long it takes to grab the image like I suggested?