# C++ capture screen fragment for further processing

Tags: c++, image, opencv, screen-capture

I'm making an application that needs to capture a fragment of the display (200x200px) very quickly (more than 30 times a second) and process the data further with openCV. I'm rewriting the application from python, where for screen capturing I used the MSS library. Can someone recommend me a lib for cpp that would prove useful for my needs? Thanks.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg` as described here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089102/2836621

Comment: But this is for Python. I need a solution for cpp

Comment: The suggestion is that you consider `ffmpeg` which is not related to C++ or Python because you don't have to write it. As regards reading the output of `ffmpeg`, you can do a `read()` just exactly the same in C++.

Comment: Yeah, but executing an external program every single time (remember, I need to capture the frames faster than 30 fps) would be xtremely inefficient as far as I understand

Comment: I'm not suggesting you run `ffmpeg` anew for each frame. I am suggesting you run it and then continuously read frames from it as fast as you want for as long as you want. If it happens to take 40ms to start it before running it for a few seconds or minutes, I can't imagine why that would matter.

Comment: You could try gstreamer. I haven't tried it myself for this specific case, but it seems possible